# Msgbox if value is selected in a cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking a VBA code for below scenario:

I've a drop down in A2 cell which states initially value as "Select"

If the value changes from select to anything else get a msgbox of the same value

Comment: You can use worksheet_Change event

Comment: I don't know the code can you help with it?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2")) Is Nothing And Range("A2") <> "Select" Then
        Msgbox "Range A2 Value is changed"
    End if
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you place the code in that worksheet's code module?

Comment: Sorry just a bit spelling mistake..

Comment: As suggested by @ExcelHero You have to place this code in VBA-Worksheet not in a module.. Please see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change